# AttributeError: _nanosecond when updating a datetime in transaction

Tags: python, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

So I am trying to update a datetime field in cloud firestore via cloud function as follows:

```
transaction.update(doc_ref, {'dateTimeField1': dateTimeValue})
```

Google sends datetime objects as string in event param of the cloud function in the format `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ` or `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ`.
For Example: `2019-01-25T15:25:03.881Z`

I am converting it to datetime object as follows:

```
try:
    datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_obj, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
except:
    datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_obj, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
datetime_obj = datetime_obj.replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC'))
```

But when I try to perform the operation I am greeted with the following error: 
`AttributeError: _nanosecond`

Traceback:
`File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1beta1/batch.py", line 112, in update
    reference._document_path, field_updates, option
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1beta1/_helpers.py", line 822, in pbs_for_update
    update_pb = extractor.get_update_pb(document_path)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1beta1/_helpers.py", line 459, in get_update_pb
    name=document_path, fields=encode_dict(self.set_fields)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1beta1/_helpers.py", line 215, in encode_dict
    return {key: encode_value(value) for key, value in six.iteritems(values_dict)}
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1beta1/_helpers.py", line 215, in <dictcomp>
    return {key: encode_value(value) for key, value in six.iteritems(values_dict)}
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1beta1/_helpers.py", line 169, in encode_value
    return document_pb2.Value(timestamp_value=value.timestamp_pb())
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/datetime_helpers.py", line 278, in timestamp_pb
    nanos = self._nanosecond or self.microsecond * 1000
AttributeError: _nanosecond`

Are datetimes allowed to be set via transactions or I am missing something here?

**EDIT:**
code snippet:

```
@firestore.transactional
def update_datetime_field(transaction, doc_ref, datetime_value):
    try:
        datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
    except:
        datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    datetime_obj = datetime_obj.replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC'))
    # Example of datetime_obj -> datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 25, 15, 25, 3, 881000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
    transaction.update(doc_ref, {'datetimeField1': datetime_obj})
    return True
```

More info:

1. The above code is triggered when a document is updated at say
   `collection1/document1/collection2/document2`
2. datetime object is python's datetime from the standard libary
3. I am trying to convert the date to UTC by changing the timezone using pytz

**EDIT 2:**

A better complete picture:

```
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

# initialize firebase admin sdk
creds = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
firebase_admin.initialize_app(creds,{'projectId': 'myProjectId'})


@firestore.transactional
def update_datetime_field(transaction, doc_ref, datetime_value):
    try:
        datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
    except:
        datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    datetime_obj = datetime_obj.replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC'))
    # Example of datetime_obj -> datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 25, 15, 25, 3, 881000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
    transaction.update(doc_ref, {'datetimeField1': datetime_obj})
    return True

def update_datetime_in_transaction(event, context):
    datetime_value = event['value']['fields']['datetimeField1']['timestampValue']
    # this looks something like 2019-01-25T15:25:03.881Z

    # prepare document reference to document
    doc_ref = prepare_doc_ref(event, context)

    # update_datetime_field
    client = firestore.client()
    transaction = client.transaction()
    update_datetime_field(transaction, doc_ref, datetime_value)

    return True
```

**EDIT 3:**

Screenshot of event param:
[image]

Screenshot of console:
[image]

Comment: I don't believe date time supports nano seconds.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete, minimal code that reproduces the problem.  Or, to put it another way, show your entire Cloud Function code, and what you are doing to trigger it.

Comment: Also, please explain what you mean by "datetime" object.  Firestore as a native Timestamp type field, which is not the same as what many systems refer to as "datetime".

Comment: @DougStevenson have updated the question with minimalistic code snippet

Comment: That doesn't look complete at all.  I don't see anything that looks like a Cloud Function trigger entry point.  What does the document look like that's triggering the change?  What's the initial value of datetime_obj that you're passing to strptime?

Comment: @DougStevenson have updated the answer with cloud function entry point. Hopefully this is provides more clarity

Comment: What is the exact type of the document field fetched by `event['value']['fields']['datetimeField1']['timestampValue']`?  Is it a proper Firestore timestamp field?  Showing a screenshot of your collection and document in the console might be helpful to understand what you're dealing with.

Comment: event['value']['fields']['datetimeField1']['timestampValue'] is a string in the format similar to `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ`. Sure will add the screenshots

Comment: @DougStevenson have added the screenshots

Comment: You are dealing with a Firestore Timestamp type.  I don't know how Cloud Functions is going to deliver that to you, but I suspect like all other Timestamp objects, it contains a property for seconds and nanosecond.  It's not a string.  You're going to have figure out how to get that representation of a Timestamp into a format that the Firestore SDK recognizes.  I don't know anything more specific than this.  The Firebase node SDKs are much easier to reason about.

Comment: If I'm not mistakes there's a bug in your code. The argument to `strptime()` should be `datetime_value`, not `datetime_obj`.

Comment: Oops sorry for the incorrectness...I have made the necessary changes...

Comment: using `pandas.Timestamp()` instead of `datetime.datetime.strptime()` solves the issue. I am guessing firestore sdk is looking for a nanosecond attribute in datetime object and its not available at the moment

Comment: I converted the `pandas.Timestamp` object to datetime object using `to_pydatetime()` and this also works. Just using `datetime.datetime.strptime()` doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So firestore python sdk expects the `_nanosecond` attribute which is not available in the python standard library's datetime at the moment (will be added in future. more details [here](https://vstinner.github.io/python37-pep-564-nanoseconds.html))

So after examining their codebase, I found a class called `DatetimeWithNanoseconds` which **adds the nanoseconds support to traditional datetime object**.

The code for the class (datetime_helpers.py file in google/api_core) is as follows (some parts deleted intentionally for brevity):

```
class DatetimeWithNanoseconds(datetime.datetime):
"""Track nanosecond in addition to normal datetime attrs.

Nanosecond can be passed only as a keyword argument.
"""
__slots__ = ('_nanosecond',)

@classmethod
def from_rfc3339(cls, stamp):
    with_nanos = _RFC3339_NANOS.match(stamp)
    if with_nanos is None:
        raise ValueError(
            'Timestamp: {}, does not match pattern: {}'.format(
                stamp, _RFC3339_NANOS.pattern))
    bare = datetime.datetime.strptime(
        with_nanos.group('no_fraction'), _RFC3339_NO_FRACTION)
    fraction = with_nanos.group('nanos')
    if fraction is None:
        nanos = 0
    else:
        scale = 9 - len(fraction)
        nanos = int(fraction) * (10 ** scale)
    return cls(bare.year, bare.month, bare.day,
               bare.hour, bare.minute, bare.second,
               nanosecond=nanos, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
```

So now, I can use this class instead of `datetime.datetime` to parse the datetime sent as string in the event param of the cloud functions using the `DatetimeWithNanoseconds.from_rfc3339(timestamp)` method.

Example:

```
from google.api_core.datetime_helpers import DatetimeWithNanoseconds

d1 = DatetimeWithNanoseconds.from_rfc3339('2019-01-25T15:25:03.881Z')
print(d1)
# DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 1, 25, 15, 25, 3, 881000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

The class also has `rfc3339()` method to give you the string representation.

Example:

```
d1.rfc3339()
# 2019-01-25T15:25:03.881Z
```

> Alternative solution:

You can use `pandas.Timestamp()` instead of `DatetimeWithNanoseconds.from_rfc3339()` too.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = pd.Timestamp('2019-01-25T15:25:03.881Z')
print(d1)
# Timestamp('2019-01-25 15:25:03.881000+0000', tz='UTC')
```

I recommend using `DatetimeWithNanoseconds` as it comes along with the sdk and you needn't add an extra dependency of pandas in the `requirements.txt` which can increase the invocation latency during the cold start. More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#functions-graceful-termination-python).

Hopefully this helps.